# how to create BitmapDescriptor from url with Fresco

Tags: android, marker, fresco

I have to use a map API and add markers in the map view.My marker is a bitmap created with local resource combined with a image from website.And I use the Fresco to load the image.

I call the BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromView(view) to get a BitmapDescriptor ,the view contains a simpleDraweeView.

The question is,I don't need to display the view to the screen,so Fresco doesn't load the Image,therefore I can't get the bitmap.How to solve it?  Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can [use the imagepipeline directly](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-image-pipeline.html) to fetch your image.
You have to use a [data subscriber](http://frescolib.org/docs/datasources-datasubscribers.html) to get a `CloseableImage`. Then you can check if the image is a `CloseableBitmap` and then do `Bitmap bitmap = (CloseableBitmap image).getUnderlyingBitmap();`.

When you subscribe, you get a reference to the image and you have to **manually close this reference once you are done with the bitmap** (do not close the bitmap directly). Otherwise this will cause memory leaks.